# How to use fixtures in WebTestCase PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, phpunit

what I try to accomplish is:
Loading fresh fixtures in PHP code before a WebTestCase is executed. As far as i know this code should do its work:

```
    // Get a kernel instance and boot it up!
    static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
    static::$kernel->boot();

    // Get entity manager
    $em = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine_phpcr.odm.default_document_manager');

    $loader = new Loader();
    foreach (self::$fixturesRequired as $fixtureClass) {
        $loader->addFixture(new $fixtureClass);
    }

    $purger = new ORMPurger($em);
    $executor = new ORMExecutor($em, $purger);
    $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());
```

... but it fails with:

```
AnnounceControllerTest::testAnnounce
Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, instance of Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\DocumentManager given, called in /opt/development/cms/.../WebTestCase.php
```

So does anyone know what I'm missing?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Hm.. I think if you will look better to error message you will get the error... Hint: ORM and ODM is differente things... maybe Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Purger/MongoDBPurger.php will help to you

Comment: Thank you for the hint! What i was looking for is PHPCRPurger and PHPCRExecutor :) both are in the same path. Now it's working! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to purge and load new fixtures for PHPCR:

```
    // Get a kernel instance and boot it up!
    static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
    static::$kernel->boot();

    // Get entity manager
    $em = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine_phpcr.odm.default_document_manager');

    $loader = new Loader();
    foreach (self::$fixturesRequired as $fixtureClass) {
        $loader->addFixture(new $fixtureClass);
    }

    $purger = new PHPCRPurger($em);
    $executor = new PHPCRExecutor($em, $purger);
    $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());
```

Thanks for the help!