# How to "doctrine:phpcr:repository:init" in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-cmf

How can I execute this code

```
php app/console doctrine:phpcr:repository:init
```

from PHP?

I want to manually initialize the repository from tests (PHPUnit) but I'm not sure what way to do it. How can I do this from PHP?

Comment: Are you dynamically creating the repository in the test? if so why?

Comment: I initially bootstrap everything in my .travis.yml ...

    - php app/console doctrine:phpcr:init:dbal --force
    - php app/console doctrine:phpcr:repository:init

Then I load the fixtures fresh right before a test is executed (not for Unit-Tests - in Unit-Tests all parts are mocked) - i need this for functional testing.

In the test i transform some parts in the repository and before the next test is executed I want to prepare the base again. This is what I try to accomplish.

Comment: dont really understand what you mean by 'transform' the repository.  Sounds to me like your tests are risky

Comment: "Transform" = CRUD operations on documents (Create, Delete, Update + Read Documents) Just an functional/e2e tests on a clean base for each test. 

So I need to init the repository before loading any fixtures. Not sure if it's really required to init the repository before running a test. It seems so. The initialized base should'nt get dropped when loading fixtures (like i do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969281/how-to-use-fixtures-in-webtestcase-phpunit/31980472#31980472) But the Initialized structure is dropped as well and so i want + need to init the repo structure.

Comment: the repository has nothing to do with the database schema.  You should have a setup/teardown method which initialises/destroys any database schema/fixtures you need for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the init command does 2 things:
1) register the default system node types
2) load initializers from Bundles

For 1) this only really needs to be done for a repository, ie. it does not need to be done for each workspace, so all that needs to be done is 2)

Here I would recommend to have a look at the CMF SE or the sandbox. In general I would recommend creating a new workspace for testing and then using fixtures to generate the required data structure.

Comment: Hi Lukas. Thx for the hints. The approach sounds good till the fact that I havn't used workspaces before :) Started now by digging into code (Workspace.php and into Unit-Tests to get a general understanding) I've also installed the sandbox (currently looking into it as well). 

Can you pls recommend a point to start for getting information on "How to use workspaces" (maybe with some code examples?). Currently not that lucky finding any in the wild and I've read the documentation (http://bit.ly/1IKxpon), looked here: http://bit.ly/1f9TtOu and here: http://bit.ly/1JeWKdv but still stuck ;)

Comment: creating a workspace can be done via the CLI https://github.com/symfony-cmf/cmf-sandbox#run-the-test-suite and you can then override the parameter with the workspace like this https://github.com/symfony-cmf/cmf-sandbox/blob/master/app/config/config_test.yml#L5

Comment: Perfect. This both looks like a good solution. Will try it right now. Thanks - i will give further Feedback within one day max. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Now i have exactly what i was looking for. I had to adjust the way how i bootstrap the base for each integration test. Now i call the commands to init the repo and load fixtures via symfony app commands. I test some aspects/verticals of the application isolated from each other as well as the whole stack and everything works perfectly. Thank you for your help!